# OnTouchEvent right after onLongClick

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have an imageview that I set OnLongClickListener on it. At the same time, I am listening to the Activity generic OnTouchEvent.  I was hoping to detect long click on a view and them start moving it using the onTouchEvent  MOVE action.

The problem is that if I longclick and then drag my finger, the OnTouchEvent does not get called. I have to lift my finger up and then press again for the OnTouchEvent to take place.

I tried returning true and returning false onLongClick but no luck.

Any reason why??

EDIT: Code added for clarification

```
MainActivity A extends Activity implements OnLongClickListener{


   public void onCreate(){
     super.OnCreate();
     setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
     ImageView iv =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage;
     iv.setOnLongClickListener();
  }

  public Boolean OnLongClick(View v){
     Log.i("On Long Click activated");
     return true;
  }
  public Boolean OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
     Log.i("OnTouch event activated");
     return super.OnTouchEvent();
  }
```

So from the above code, if you long click a view and move your finger (even outside the view) without lifting your finger up then only the following log will be shown:
"On Long Click activated"

Comment: please post some code, what you tried for it

Comment: Hope I understand right from your words, Its not what you are assuming to be call `OnLongClickListener` after `onTouchEvent`. But, when you simply Touch means only `onTouchEvent` event should call and when long click then only `OnLongClickListener`  should call.

Comment: I added code for reference.

Comment: Mobi I think you misunderstood my question..check out code for clarification

Comment: Long clickable views consume all touch events, even after the long press has been performed, regardless of whether the long press is handled. Therefore no touch event would be allowed to be passed up to the `Activity` level. You should set a touch listener on the `ImageView` instead.

Comment: The problem is that no touch event is generated even after I drag my finger outside the view. I guess the long click is still in effect. If i use the ontouch instead, I will lose the long click feature.

Comment: Yes, touch events belong to the (handling) `View` on which they were initiated, even after moving out of it's bounds. Using a touch listener will not invalidate the long click listener if you don't handle the touch until the long press has been performed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer of your problem

```
//var
float dX, dY ;
 yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onTouch");
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            float right = size.x - yourImageView.getWidth();
            float bottom = size.y - yourImageView.getHeight() * 1.5f;
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG,"actionDown");

                    dX = yourImageView.getX();
                    dY = yourImageView.getY();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Valores: " + String.valueOf(dX) + " " + String.valueOf(dY));
                   return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d(TAG,"actionMove");

                    yourImageView.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() - yourImageView.getWidth())
                            .y(event.getRawY() - yourImageView.getHeight())
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG,"actionUp");
                    if(dX == yourImageView.getX() && dY == yourImageView.getY()){
                        onclick_yourImageView(v); // this is the event todo when you click over image
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (yourImageView.getY() > 1000) {
                        float left = event.getRawX();
                        if (left < 0) {
                            left = 0;
                        }
                        yourImageView.animate()
                                .x(left - yourImageView.getWidth())
                                .y(bottom)
                                .setDuration(200)
                                .start();
                    } else if (yourImageView.getX() < size.x / 2) {
                        yourImageView.animate()
                                .x(0)
                                .y(event.getRawY() - yourImageView.getHeight())
                                .setDuration(400)
                                .start();
                    } else {
                        yourImageView.animate()
                                .x(right)
                                .y(event.getRawY() - yourImageView.getHeight())
                                .setDuration(400)
                                .start();
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Paste this code in your proyect and when only click the position of the image not change and for this rareason do the method **onclick_yourImageView(v);**

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar issue and believe I might have a simpler solution. I found that onLongClick from OnLongClickListener would not behave correctly if onTouch or onTouchEvent were also fired. I'm still not totally sure why, but onLongClick was fired on *every* click, regardless how long.

My solution was to **implement OnLongClickListener, and when onLongClick is fired, attach the onTouchListener I desired**. In your case, once onLongClick fires, you attach the touchListener to allow for moving of the view. I found that an OnTouchListener works better than overriding the View's onTouchEvent, and gives you all the same information.

The final step of the solution is to **remove the onTouchListener on ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL**. That way, you won't start moving the object again until another long click. See stubbed code below:

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //perform other view setup based on attributes
        setOnLongClickListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        return false; //if you want haptics on the long click, return true
    }

    private OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    setOnTouchListener(null);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    setOnTouchListener(null);
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //do your moving stuff
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
       }
   };
}
```